# How to output vertical bar format in textfile

Tags: python, file-io, text-files, fwrite

I am trying to save my contents in the textfile in this format

```
|Name|Description|

|QY|Hello|
```

But for now mine is returning me as this output:

```
|2014 1Q    2014 2Q 2014 3Q 2014 4Q|

|96,368.3   96,808.3    97,382  99,530.5|
```

Code:

```
def write_to_txt(header,data):
    with open('test.txt','a+') as f:
        f.write("|{}|\n".format('\t'.join(str(field) 
                          for field in header))) # write header 
        f.write("|{}|\n".format('\t'.join(str(field) 
                          for field in data))) # write items
```

Any idea how to change my code so that I would have the ideal output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happenning because you are joining the fields inside data iterable using `\t` , use `|` in the join as well for your requirement. Example -

```
def write_to_txt(header,data):
    with open('test.txt','a+') as f:
        f.write("|{}|\n".format('|'.join(str(field) 
                          for field in header))) # write header 
        f.write("|{}|\n".format('|'.join(str(field) 
                          for field in data)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Such a simple change needed only =)

Comment: Welcome , glad to be of help.